# How to work with a simple txt file in Xamarin forms (Portable)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to Create and read a simple txt 
in Xamarin forms portable class

how can I do that? and what is the best way to do that?
would be happy for a code example

thanks for the answers.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example (Working with files in Xamarin.Forms): https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/